# how to add blank rows after few rows and after blank rows next rows starts from last numbers

Tags: php, mysqli, database-design

This is my code

```
<form name="#" method="POST" action="#">
 <input type="text"  id="id" name="tid" />
<input type="text"  id="name" name="name" />
<input type="text"  id="addnumber" name="addnumber">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Save Infomation" style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">                 
</form>
```

This is Php my code

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $Id=$_POST['id'];
        $Name=$_POST['name'];
        $Numbers=$_POST['addnumber'];
```

if in`$_POST['addnumber']` user enter 5 then it create 5 row 1 to 5. thenAfter 5 row creation i want to add 2 or 3 blank spaces (Rows) . thenafter again enter 5 rows and they must start from 6 to 10  like  (1-5, 3 blank rows, 6-10 )

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $Numbers; $i++){
        $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tablename(Id,Name,Number) VALUES('".$Id."','".$Name."','".$i."')");
        echo "<h1> Infomation Saved</h1>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code bellow insert 5 row ,then a blank row then 5 row then a blank row ,......

1
2
3
4
5

6
7
8
9
10
11
.
.
.
.

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= $Numbers; $i++){
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tablename(Id,Name,Number)    VALUES('".$Id."','".$Name."','".$i."')");

    if($i%5==0) 
      $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tablename(Id,Name,Number)    VALUES('NULL','NULL',0) ");

    echo "<h1> Infomation Saved</h1>";
}

?>
```

Comment: but sir if i want to add 5 records then after want to add number of my choice like, this time i want to add 4 blank rows after that again add to 3 number containing row and then after want to add 5 blank rows..but last rows must starts after first five record count-like 1-5 then 3 blank rows and then 6-10  hows it possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $Numbers; $i++){

    if($i % 5 == 0){

        echo '&nbsp'; 
        echo '<br/>';
    }

    }
```

Comment: okay .thenafter blank rows ..if user enter again 5 row must starts from 6 to 10 ..how can be its possible

Comment: make the id as auto increment value in your database so that you can get what you have needed